# Can I two way bind a model property in ember without a template for the component?

Tags: ember.js, ember-addon

I have a simple ember component

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'input',
    type: 'text',
    attributeBindings: ['value', 'type']
});
```

I'm trying to "not" require a template (on purpose) ... but when I remove the template it no longer binds back to the controller (here was the template I had)

```
{{input value=value}}
```

... it doesn't update the model/or controller (simple controller below)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    number: ''
});
```

Here is the working jsbin to show the issue

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/puqepaqijo/1/

note: if you add the template it works ... but I'd like to build this/bind this without having to require my own template ships with the ember-cli addon

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/puqepaqijo/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1) extend `Ember.TextField`
2) have a `layout` property instead of a template itself.

Apparently, there was a reason they extended `{{input}}` instead of making us all do `<input {{bind-attr value=value}}>` :)

Comment: that did work but I'm curious if what I showed above is a *bug* or the expected behavior. ie- what would the core team say